# If condition executes even it is false?

Tags: grails, groovy

```
def findFdrsWithMaturityYear(year){
       def fdrs = Fdr.findAll()
       def foundFdrs = new ArrayList<Fdr>()
        def foundYear
        fdrs.each {
            foundYear = DateUtils.getYearFromDate(it.maturityDate)
            if (year.toString() == foundYear.toString()){ // line 7
                foundFdrs.add(it)  // line 8
            }
        }
        return foundFdrs
    }
```

Above is groovy code. I'm debugging it with intellijidea 11, when I reach at line no 7, I found that even if the condition is false, it goes to line no 8, but foundFdrs list does not grow as it adds one element in the list. I'm using this code in a grails web app, every time I run this web app, I get empty foundFdr list even if condition at line no 7 is true. I also tested above code by creating a grails integration test, test passes successfully, ie I get foundFdrs list with some elements, but not in my grails app, Where is the problem ?

Comment: why don't we add println statement in the if clause? We may see if 2 variable is truly equals or not.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that despite the debugger showing that line as being executed, it isn't in fact executed

Not sure why you are doing toString on both vars either...

Comment: Add some logging inside the if-statement to determine if it really is executing this branch

Answer (score -3):

A safe option would be to use simply use [StringUtils#equals](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#equals%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

as two string may or may not be compared by using "=="

Comment: Could you please let us know why do u think the answer is not good? as StringUtils provides a convenient, and null safe way to compare two strings. What's wrong with the approach? I really like to know why you felt to vote down

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but this is groovy, and `==` is all you need

Answer (score -4):

I would assume the problem lies within the "if" condition.  You have year.toString() == foundYear.toString() which is essentially saying "if (string == string)", however the == operator may not be overloaded to compare strings in Groovy (I do not know Groovy really, but I program in Java and Scala).  Look through the Groovy documentation and see if there is any "equals" method for string comparison, since I highly doubt that the == operator will do what you were intending.  Hope this helps a little bit!

Since Groovy is a Java-like language, you may want to check this out = http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/qanda/pjqa00001.shtml

Comment: `"a" == str` is fine in groovy

Comment: Ah, so I see now.  I went on a loos assumption that it followed the Java convention, my fault.  Thanks!